# Create multiple files using PowerShell with sample content?

Tags: powershell

I was able to create 1M files in my folder using PowerShell like this. Can anyone help me with how to add some sample text while creating the file?

```
1..1000000 | foreach {new-item -path C:\Testdata$_.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1):

```sh
1..1000000 | ForEach-Object {
    Out-File -InputObject 'Sample Text' -FilePath C:\Testdata$_.txt
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Santiago. It worked perfectly.

11..15 | ForEach-Object {Out-File -InputObject 'Sample Text' -FilePath J:\Testdata\textfile$_.txt}

Answer (score 0):

If you see the syntaxt for

```
New-Item
[-Path] <String[]>
[-ItemType <String>]
[-Value <Object>]
[-Force]
[-Credential <PSCredential>]
[-WhatIf]
[-Confirm]
[<CommonParameters>]
```

We are going to use `-ItemType` and `-Value` so that the file is created with the default value/text given

**Here is a very basic example which will create `testfile1.txt` with defa**

```
New-Item -Path . -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
```

Now using your initial command we could do like below

```
1..1000000 | foreach {new-item -path C:\Testdata$_.txt -ItemType File -Value "The first sentence in our file."}
```

Comment: Glad to know that. If it helped, please accept the answer